# How to display multiple GoogleMaps in a list with Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I try to display multiple cards in a list.
Each card is displaying a google maps (using google_maps_flutter plugin) .

When I try to display multiple cards / maps. A crash occurs (on iOS).

The crash: Flutter`SkPictureRecorder::getRecordingCanvas:

It seems related to this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28416 , but I do not find any workarround yet

Any solution /advice ?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround may be using the static api to get map image for each card in list: [static google map api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro)